# auto fill textarea if dropdown option is selected

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `select` and a `textarea`.
I want to fill the `textarea` if the `select` element is changed.
Here's my HTML code (I can't edit it, so i need jQuery) :

```
<div class="event-attributes">
    <select name="em_attributes[room]">
        <option>room 1</option>
        <option>room 2</option>
        <option>room 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="event-attributes">
    <label for="em_attributes[Room detail]">Room detail</label>
    <textarea id="" cols="55" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
```

If I select room 1, the `textarea` must change its value to "this is a room description", etc.

i trying:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mytextbox = document.getElementById('textareaID');
    var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdownID');

    mydropdown.onchange = function(){
    mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value; //to appened
    //mytextbox.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
    </script>
```

but i have no ID for Options or textarea

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted to write yourself to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just go through below code and Demo

HTML :-

```
<div class="event-attributes"></div>
<select name="em_attributes[room]" id="slt">
    <option>room 1</option>
    <option>room 2</option>
    <option>room 3</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="event-attributes">
<label for="em_attributes[Room detail]">Room detail</label>
<textarea id="txt" cols="55" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>
```

jqUERY:-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#slt").on('change', function() {

        $("#txt").val("You selected : " + $(this).val());
    });
    });
```

UPDATE :-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("select[name='em_attributes[room]']").on('change', function() {

        $("textarea ").val("selected :"+ $(this).val() + " this is the " + $(this).val() + " description  "  );
});
});
```

Demo :-

http://jsfiddle.net/LbLHc/4/

Comment: I have updated plz check and let me know for any query @carl1304IT

Comment: great now it work but i need something that fill textarea like:

*selected room 1*
this is the room description
*selected room 2*
this is room 2 description

Comment: thank you, and is possible to have a different text for every option select?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // apply a change event
    $('#drodownid').change(function() {
        // update input box with the currently selected value
        $('#textboxid').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

```
$('select').on('change',function (){

        $('textarea').val("this is a room description")


});
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, it is better to provide an explanation *why* it is correct.